# GraphQL Text Type invalid argument

Tags: graphql

Using the type `Text` defined in [scaphold.io API](https://scaphold.io/docs/#scalars), I'm trying to make the following mutation where `content` is of type "Text", but I'm getting the following error: "BadRequestError: Invalid input values."
Does anyone know why is that happening? It works when the content type is string.

```
mutation {
   createPost (input: {
      content: "d"
   }) 
   {
      changedPost {
         content
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How does type `Text` look like?

Comment: "  The 'Text' scalar type is like String except can hold values of much longer length.
  The String type has a max length of 767 bytes due to indexing constraints.
  Text on the other hand can hold values of up to a length of 2^16 bytes.". It's defined at scaphold.io

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `Text` type isn't a Scalar type, which means you can't input a scalar value of "d" into the input.

For a Text type with particular fields, your input might look something like this:

```
input: {
    content: {
        body: "d"
    }
}
```

Given that body is a field of the Text type. Hope this helps!